# Can't Debug Failing SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

## Code/Info

I have this **query**:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `tap_sajobs` (
    `ja_jid`,
    `ja_reference`,
    `ja_datePosted`,
    `ja_dateUpdated`,
    `ja_title`,
    `ja_summary`,
    `ja_description`,
    `ja_location`,
    `ja_email`,
    `ja_url`,
    `ja_salaryperiod`,
    `ja_salarymin`,
    `ja_salarymax`
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

The values are filled by the array `$ja`. **I can simulate the query with this**:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `tap_sajobs` (`ja_jid`,`ja_reference`,`ja_datePosted`,`ja_dateUpdated`,`ja_title`,`ja_summary`,`ja_description`,`ja_location`,`ja_email`,`ja_url`,`ja_salaryperiod`,`ja_salarymin`,`ja_salarymax`)
VALUES (".implode(",",$ja).");";
echo $query;
```

Which outputs the following:

```
INSERT INTO `tap_sajobs` (`ja_jid`,`ja_reference`,`ja_datePosted`,`ja_dateUpdated`,`ja_title`,`ja_summary`,`ja_description`,`ja_location`,`ja_email`,`ja_url`,`ja_salaryperiod`,`ja_salarymin`,`ja_salarymax`)
    VALUES ('2049216', '2091046', '2015-07-23', '2015-08-20T06:49:30Z', 'Consultant', 'Will consider a graduate or a fully qualified fellow.', 'Test', 'No Location Set', 'test@foo.com', 'https://test.foo.com/3207/2049216/vh6zpeigfx6edggjrhshwulvvy?site=live', '0', '0', '0')
```

The actual **code to execute the query** is:

```
if(!$stmt->execute($ja)) { 
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    exit("Error communicating with database.");
}
```

## Problem

When executing the query via code, I see the error "Error communicating with database" and `$dbh->errorInfo()` outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) 1
```

However, **executing the query as outputted by the PHP code directly into phpMyAdmin executes without issue**.

What is the source of this issue, or how can I find it?

Comment: $stmt->execute() use without params

Comment: Why is everyone suggesting this? `$stmt->execute()` requires an array parameter if there are placeholders in the query statement.

Comment: Are you sure there are values in array ?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Yes, otherwise `$query` would output blank values!

Comment: How does `$ja` look like?

Comment: The contents of `$ja` are outputted in the value `$query` in the question - values from `$ja[0]` to `$ja[12]` are `'2049216', '2091046', '2015-07-23', '2015-08-20T06:49:30Z', 'Consultant', 'Will consider a graduate or a fully qualified fellow.', 'Test', 'No Location Set', 'test@foo.com', 'https://test.foo.com/3207/2049216/vh6zpeigfx6edggjrhshwulvvy?site=live', '0', '0', '0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLSTATE` code `00000` tells you that no error is occurred in the last executed statement. The following line will return `0` if no row is affected by the sql query.

```
$stmt->execute($ja);
```

So, you will go inside the `if` block even if there are no errors, because `!$stmt->execute($ja)` will be equal to `1`. Therefore to catch error, I think it is better to use,

```
$result = $stmt->execute($ja);
if($result == false) {
    // put the error handling logic here.
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why or how, but changing my code to execute the query as you wrote it has solved the issue. I don't get it. `$stmt->execute($ja)` wasn't working and was returning `false`, but `$result = $stmt->execute($ja)` inputted data correctly and executed without a problem. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `tap_sajobs` (`ja_jid`, `ja_reference`, `ja_datePosted`, `ja_dateUpdated`, `ja_title`, `ja_summary`, `ja_description`, `ja_location`, `ja_email`, `ja_url`, `ja_salaryperiod`, `ja_salarymin`, `ja_salarymax`)
VALUES (".implode(",", $ja).");";
echo $query;
```

yields

```
INSERT INTO `tap_sajobs` (`ja_jid`, `ja_reference`, `ja_datePosted`, `ja_dateUpdated`, `ja_title`, `ja_summary`, `ja_description`, `ja_location`, `ja_email`, `ja_url`, `ja_salaryperiod`, `ja_salarymin`, `ja_salarymax`)
VALUES ('2049216', '2091046', '2015-07-23', '2015-08-20T06:49:30Z', 'Consultant', 'Will consider a graduate or a fully qualified fellow.', 'Test', 'No Location Set', 'test@foo.com', 'https://test.foo.com/3207/2049216/vh6zpeigfx6edggjrhshwulvvy?site=live', '0', '0', '0')
```

then it seems that all the values in `$ja` are **already escaped**, so when you use the array to prepare the statement, they would get double escaped, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to delete quotes on your table

```
'tap_sajobs'
```

try this

```
 tap_sajobs
```

Answer (score -1):

You are executing "ja", not "query":

```
if(!$stmt->execute($ja))
```

Execute the query instead:

```
if(!$stmt->execute($query))
```

Comment: My statement is prepared earlier with `$query`, and `execute` requires the array to bind statements in the query, no? (`$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query); $stmt->execute($foo);`)

Comment: You are correct, but the shown code is not complete - so I had to guess.

Comment: What more code do you want to see? `$ja` is the array, I've written out the prepared statement, I've shown the values of `$ja` in the query and the error handling and the errors...?

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. To find the problem, I would try alternative ways of doing it. Perhaps try the way of Example #4 in http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php